What's the best practice in a Spring Boot 3 project using Gradle Kotlin to publish Maven artifacts of both the fat jar and an openapi json document?
Environment:

Spring Boot 3 app written in Kotlin (bootstrapped from https://start.spring.io)
Gradle Kotlin 8.7

Requirements:

Publish generated openapi json specification as a Maven artifact
Publish Spring Boot fat jar as a Maven artifact (not for use in other projects -- for use with other tooling that has to do with packaging the app)

Current build.gradle.kts snippet:
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("FatJar") {
            artifact(tasks.bootJar.get())
        }

        create<MavenPublication>("AppApiOpenApi") {

            artifact("${file(project.layout.buildDirectory).absolutePath}/openapi.json") {
                classifier = "openapi"
            }
            pom {
                packaging = "json"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories { /* ... */ }
}

Current output (names scrubbed):

Build-time warning like this: Multiple publications with coordinates 'com.blah:app-api:0.11.0-dev.0' are published to repository 'mavenLocal'. The publications 'FatJar' in project ':app-api' and 'AppApiOpenApi' in project ':app-api' will overwrite each other!
Two artifact files are correctly produced from ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal into my local maven repo (~/.m2/repository/com/blah/0.11.0-dev.0):  app-api-0.11.0-dev.0-openapi.json & site-app-0.11.0-dev.0.jar.  Both files have the correct content.
I suspect the pom file is incorrect.  See below.

The generated pom file is this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.blah</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.0-dev.0</version>
  <packaging>json</packaging>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-annotations-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-daemon-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-js</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-js</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk7</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-main-kts</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-script-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-scripting-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-scripting-ide-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-scripting-jvm-host</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-scripting-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler-embeddable</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.23</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>

I feel like the POM should not contain any dependencies because this is a fat jar, and the packaging is json, which only refers to the openapi spec.
My question is:  how should I craft the publications section so that I publish the two artifacts without the warning and so that the pom correctly describes the two artifacts?
